# Select rows that match arbitrary criterias

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySql table like this:

```
ID  Category    Value
A   LOCATION    COPENHAGEN
A   LOCATION    MADRID
B   LOCATION    MADRID
C   LOCATION    MADRID
C   LOCATION    AARHUS
C   POSITION    WEBDESIGN
D   POSITION    SYSADMIN
D   POSITION    WEBDESIGN
A   GENDER      MALE
B   GENDER      MALE
C   GENDER      FEMALE
```

Id, Category and Values together forms the key. Note that they are dynamic (user defined) and the table will be large.

Now I want to get all `ID` that match some criteria. To be returned, it is enough for the `ID` to match one value within each `Category`.

For example:

GIVE ME ALL IDS WHO HAVE

> ((LOCATION = COPENHAGEN OR LOCATION = MADRID) AND (GENDER = MALE))

should return A, B

Another example:

GIVE ME ALL IDS WHO HAVE

```
((POSITION = SYSADMIN OR POSITION = WEBDESIGN) AND (GENDER = FEMALE) AND (LOCATION = COPENHAGEN OR LOCATION = MADRID))
```

should return C

The returned ids are to be used as a subquery for another query - so performance matters.

**UPDATE**

I've created this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3578f/1) with sample data and a proposed not working solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Removed initial response as it was non-functional. In making it functional I came up with the query in the second edit which is much preferable.]

---

### Edit

It seems like you're trying to create a schema to keep track of people working in various locations, and from your data it seems like they might hold multiple titles among various offices. The below schema would allow you to define each person, job, and location only once and then connect them using a linking table.

```
TABLE People
  p_id INT AI PK
  p_name VARCHAR
  p_sex BOOL
  ...

TABLE Offices
  o_ID INT AI PK
  o_name VARCHAR
  o_location VARCHAR
  ...

TABLE Jobs
  j_ID INT AI PK
  j_name VARCHAR
  ...

TABLE People_Jobs_Offices  --linking table
  p_ID INT PK
  o_ID INT PK
  j_ID INT PK
```

Now get all of the Sysadmins in Madrid or Copenhagen:

```
SELECT *
FROM People_Jobs_Offices pjo
  INNER JOIN People p
    ON pjo.p_id = p.p_id 
  INNER JOIN Jobs j
    on pjo.j_id = j.j_id
  INNER JOIN Offices o
    ON pjo.o_id = o.o_id
WHERE
  j.j_name = 'SYSADMIN'
  AND ( o.o_location = 'MADRID'
    OR o.o_location = 'COPENHAGEN' )
```

This approach is called [Database Normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm), and generally makes the best use of indexes in any RDBMS, as well as keeping the number of rows in your tables to a minimum by avoiding the duplication of data.

---

### Edit²

I've [re-fiddled your SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c6e/1/0). Much of this would have to be done porgrammatically, ie. determining which categories/how many joins/table aliases/column names, but you'd want to start out with whatever table the `ID` column references so you have a solid starting point for these joins, I've just created the `users` table for illustration.

```
CREATE TABLE users (`ID` varchar(16),`name` varchar(16));
INSERT INTO users (`ID`, `name`)
VALUES ('A', 'andrew'), ('B', 'bob'), ('C', 'charla');
```

And the query:

```
SELECT u.*,
  gen.value 'gender',
  pos.value 'position',
  loc.value 'location'
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN yourtable gen
    ON u.ID = gen.ID
      AND gen.category = 'GENDER'
  LEFT JOIN yourtable pos
    ON u.id = pos.id
      AND pos.category = 'POSITION'
  LEFT JOIN yourtable loc
    ON u.id = loc.id
      AND loc.category = 'LOCATION'
```

And the output:

```
ID  NAME    GENDER  POSITION    LOCATION
A   andrew  MALE    (null)      COPENHAGEN
A   andrew  MALE    (null)      MADRID
B   bob     MALE    WEBDESIGN   MADRID
B   bob     MALE    SYSADMIN    MADRID
C   charla  FEMALE  (null)      MADRID
C   charla  FEMALE  (null)      AARHUS
```

I would also make certain that, with the potential for *many* joins, you have indexes on `category` as well as `ID`, if not all 3 columns in the table.

Comment: Could you guide me into a better db design?

Comment: I cant get this working, could you write the complete select query where at least two categories are in play?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. My design is however more abstract than you describe and I believe my db design is sound. Let me explain the scenario: I have x users. Each user can create as many categories as they wish (rendered as fieldset with header and description). In each category they can create as many options as they wish (these are rendered as checkboxes with a label). The table in my question holds respondents answer to these options, a checked checkbox gives one row in the table.

Comment: Your query will never return rows if more than one category is in play, check out this sql fiddle: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3578f/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3578f/1)

Comment: I've [re-fiddled](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c6e/1/0) and also updated my answer to include the info.

Answer (score 1):

The solution - for the moment - is to make a subquery for each category. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT ID from yourtable WHERE (Category = 'POSITION' AND Value = 'SYSADMIN'))
AND ID IN 
(SELECT ID from yourtable WHERE (Category = 'LOCATION' AND Value = 'MADRID') OR (Category = 'LOCATION' AND Value = 'COPENHAGEN'))
```

Working example can be seen here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3578f/4).

It is working, but I am worried about performance when I have many rows or am checking in many categories.